# printing 2 times donno why

Tags: java, printing

I am having a problem when i break out from remove part the code prints main menu options twice

There is no error in code and it runs properly but why does it print twice instead of once?

```
 public void mainloop() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

        String x;

        System.out.println("Please Select your option");
        System.out.println("............................");
        System.out.println("1 ADD NAME AND NUMBER \n2 REMOVE NAME AND NUMBER \n3 SEARCH NAME AND NUMBER \n0 EXIT");
        System.out.println("............................");

        x = input.nextLine();

        if (x.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
            System.out.println("Thank you!");
            break;
        }
        if (x.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
            String Name;
            String Number;

            System.out.println("Please Enter your Name below");
            Name = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please Enter your Number below");
            Number = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Your Name " + Name + " and Number " + Number + " has been saved!\n");

            objectclass objectclassObject = new objectclass(Name, Number);
            Test.add(objectclassObject);
        }
        if (x.equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {

            System.out.println("-------ALL NAME AND NUMBERS-------");
            System.out.println("");

            for (int j = 0; j < Test.size();) {
                objectclass p = Test.get(j++);
                System.out.println(j + ". Name: " + p.getName() + " - " + p.getNumber());
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < Test.size(); j++) {
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Enter Index number to remove Contact from Phonebook!");
                int v = input.nextInt();
                int temp = (v - 1);
                if (v >= 1 && v <= Test.size()) {
                    System.out.println("Name: " + Test.get(temp).getName() + " And Number: " + Test.get(temp).getNumber() + " has been removed!!");
                    System.out.println("");
                    Test.remove(temp);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Please enter number properly!!");
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        if (x.equalsIgnoreCase("3")) {
            String y;
            System.out.println("*** Enter your Name below for search ***");
            y = input.nextLine();

            for (objectclass p : Test) {
                String z = p.getName();
                if (z.equalsIgnoreCase(y)) {
                    System.out.println("Your Name is: " + p.getName() + "\nYour Number is: " + p.getNumber());
                    System.out.println("");
                }
                if (!z.equalsIgnoreCase(y)) {
                    System.out.println("Contact not found!!!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
System.out.println("Please Select your option");
System.out.println("............................");
System.out.println("1 ADD NAME AND NUMBER \n2 REMOVE NAME AND NUMBER \n3 SEARCH NAME AND NUMBER \n0 EXIT");
System.out.println("............................");
```

this prints twice :/~

Comment: Firstly change if to switch statements makes it readable in your case..

Comment: i am new to java ... learning things 1 by 1 :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this prints twice, you went 2 times thru the loop.  Try to display the variable 'x' after reading it.  I bet you have extra empty strings between your legitimate input.

What happens is that nextInt() doesn't consume the newline.  Therefore, the next time you read x you read the end of the line after the value v.

Comment: how can i fix it then?

Comment: Follow your input.nextInt() with an input.nextLine().

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Aeshang please use Switch instead of if.
Secondly

```
if (x.equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
```

block does not end before

```
if (x.equalsIgnoreCase("3")) {
```

Your remove part also includes search part. Not sure if this will solve the problem but first correct these things and check your answer.

Comment: i dont think my remove part includes search part :s